# Magento PDF invoice - edit order and names of subtotal, tax and total field

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I see that when I print my Magento PDF invoice for an order, I get wrong names and order at the bottom of the document for price of the product, product tax, delivery costs and total fields.

Is it possible to edit thoose fields from some phtml file, or all magento pdf invoices are edited through invoice and abstract.php files?

If second option is true, how to change names and order for pdf invoice items mentioned before ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @

- [Customize Magento PDF Invoice and Packingslip](http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-magento-pdf-invoice-and-packingslip/)
- [Edit an invoice PDF](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf)

You will need to rewrite `order_pdf_invoice` (or copying it to app/local/Mage)

```
<models>
    <sales>
        <rewrite>                    
            <order_pdf_invoice>Atwix_Printedorders_Model_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
        </rewrite>
    </sales>
...
</models>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento PDF's don't use PHTML and yes you will have to preferably override the necessary .php files to make changes to the PDF. PDF's use Zend's Zend_Pdf library and run on a coordinate system where 0,0 is the bottom left of the page.

The necessary file that will require overriding to is located \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Default.php.
The names can be edited by editing the necessary locale csv in app\locale\\Mage_Sales.csv however this will likely change any other instances of that text.